# How do i get my React components to render in a timely fashion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setinterval

I'm working on a react project, and i've been trying to have Message components render at a certain pace, this is what i have now:

```js
    const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([])

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const input = inputValue;
        setinputValue("")
        if (input && inputHandler(input)) {
            const newMessages = inputHandler(input)
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (!newMessages.length) return clearInterval(interval)
                setChatMessages([...chatMessages, newMessages.shift()])
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

inputHandler() returns an array of objects that i want to add individually to the state, setChatMessages() changes the state, and then the chatMessages state gets mapped to create my Message components.

This code works properly for single messages, but if inputHandler() returns more than 1 message, only one new message is added, and it cycles between all the messages in the array until it stops at the last one.

It seems that the chatMessages state isn't updating between iterations, anyone knows how i can work around this?

Comment: If you want all the messages in `newMessages` dont use `shift()` that only does one element. Use the same spread operator you did with `chatMessages`, eg `[...chatMessages, ...newMessages]`

Comment: I dont want them to be added at the same time, i need them to be added every 500ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i managed to behave like i want it to with this:

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (!newMessages.length) return clearInterval(interval)
                chatMessages = [...chatMessages, newMessages.shift()]
                setChatMessages([...chatMessages])
            }, 500);
```

feel like this code is a war crime, but it works

Answer (score 0):

First, cache `newMessages` in a queue after `const newMessages = inputHandler(input)`. Second, check the queue every 500ms, you can use an array to do that. If the queue is not empty, pop the first one.

Comment: I don't think that helps with my issue, the state still wouldn't be updated for the next iteration

Comment: I assumed you know that after popping the first one, call ```setChatMessages([...chatMessages, firstOne])```. This doesn't work?

Comment: Can you explain how your solution is different from what i'm already trying?

My main problem is with the state not updating for the next iteration, and i honestly don't understand how yours would help, might be a bit over my paygrade.

Comment: I do not know how your ```setChatMessages``` implemented. It might be something like ```setChatMessages(msgs) { setState({messages: msgs});}```, then in your render(), return something with ```state.messages```.  
What I did, was when ```handleSubmit``` is triggered, cache the new messages from  ```inputHandler``` into a queue, on the other side, you have a timer or setInterval to consume the queue. So whenever there is another ```handleSubmit``` event, the queue can be filled, and a new message from the top of the queue is appended to render() by ```setChatMessages->setState``` every 500ms.

Comment: I'm using the ```setState()``` hook in a functional component, ```setChatMessages()``` directly updates the state

Comment: You can post your code as well.  But you know the way I proposed, right?